# Reading blob from table using pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, blob

I have a blob column in my table that contains number of images (let's say four images). Its structure is like this

- index of the image ( 1 byte) || image (X bytes X OS the length of the image )
- index of the image ( 1 byte) || image (X bytes X OS the length of the image )
- index of the image ( 1 byte) || image (X bytes X OS the length of the image )
- index of the image ( 1 byte) || image (X bytes X OS the length of the image )

I need to select just one image from that blob ( let's say I want to save the second one into an other blob) using pl SQL.

Is that possible, if yes I would be thankful if anyone of you guys would help me

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statement. Also: why do you want a stored procedure? What exactly do you want to do with the image in the stored procedure?

Comment: My  problem is with the structure of the blob not the table, and I want a stored procedure to use it in forms to separate the images on execution.